# Problems with i18next js

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I am trying out an example for understanding `i18next` js. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Internationalization example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="i18next.amd-1.10.1/i18next.amd-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="i18next.amd-1.10.1/i18next.amd.withJQuery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        i18n.init(function(err, t) {
          // translate nav
          $(".nav").i18n();

          // programatical access
          var appName = t("app.name");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.home"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <p>There are so many countries in the world, and hence many languages exist. So translating the website to each country's official language is important</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`locales/en/translation.json:`**

```
{
  "app": {
    "name": "i18next"
  },
  "nav": {
    "home": "Home",
    "page1": "Page One",
    "page2": "Page Two"
  }
}
```

But I don't get anything on browser. I'm not using npm for installing i18next js. I'm just using it directly as shown in `html` code. How can I make it work?

Comment: Does `"i18next.amd-1.10.1/i18next.amd-1.10.1.js"` exist on your server?

Comment: Yes, it exists on my server

Comment: After you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: yeah, I'm familiar with jQuery

Comment: So you should probably know... if you want to use it, you need to import it into your page